# How do you merge duplicate rows in a table in BigQuery - replacing missing values with most recent records

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For example, I have a table of leads from a marketing database. There are multiple records with duplicate email values. I'd like to merge all of the duplicate records to roll up into the latest updated record and if the latest updated record is missing values for certain fields then update those fields from other records most recently updated.

Table:

| First | last | Email | Phone | Job Title | State | Last Updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | john.doe@example.com |  |  | MD | 1/1/2019 |
| John | low | john.doe@example.com | 1234567891 | Coach | VA | 1/1/2018 |
| John | Doe | john.doe@example.com | 3214569875 | Teacher | CA | 1/1/2017 |
| Andy | Yes | john.doe@example.com |  |  | DC | 1/1/2021 |
| Roby | Doe | john.doe@example.com | 8628423578 | Scientist | VA | 1/1/2025 |

Output - One record:

| First | last | Email | Phone | Job Title | State | Last Updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | Yes | john.doe@example.com | 1234567891 | Coach | DC | 1/1/2021 |

In this example, since the 2021 record is missing a phone number and job title, those values are pulled from the most recent updated records (2018).

I've thought about using Distinct or Unique functions but not sure how to execute on the merge using the last updated record and then filling in the blank values with the other most recent records. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Dawit

Comment: why `1/1/2025` row is ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach - I think it is most generic - you need just make sure you have correct list of fields in unpivot and pivot lines. Though there is an assumption that following fields (First, Last, Phone, Job_Title, State) are all of string data type

```
select First, Last, Email, Phone, Job_Title, State, max_Last_Updated as Last_Updated
from (
  select * except(Last_Updated), 
    max(Last_Updated) over(partition by Email) as max_Last_Updated
  from data
  unpivot (value for col in (First, Last, Phone, Job_Title, State))
  where true
  qualify row_number() over(partition by Email, col order by Last_Updated desc) = 1
)
pivot (max(value) for col in ('First', 'Last', 'Phone', 'Job_Title', 'State', 'Last_Updated'))
```

If applied to sample data in your question (excluding 2025 row) - output is

[image]

Comment: Yes! My fault I meant to post earlier but got caught up in some fixes. It worked like a charm! I saw you're not about making sure all values were string values so I had to adjust for that a bit. 

I found some records that had the same Last_updated time (not that many), so it still had some dupes for those, but it wasn't that many so I wrote another query to fix for those.

Answer (score 0):

You need a method to know that these are all the same record.  You can use `last_value(ignore nulls)` for this purpose:

```
select t.*,
       last_value(first ignore nulls) over (partition by email order by last_updated) as imputed_first,
       last_value(last ignore nulls) over (partition by email order by last_updated) as imputed_first,
       . . .   -- and so on for the other columns
from t;
```